# Как изменить значение переменной другого контроллера AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

У меня есть два контроллера:

```
 <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <div ng-controller="SecondController">{{number}}</div>
    </div>
```

Также у меня есть фабрика метод, который возвращает число внутри обоих контроллеров:

```
$scope.number = Number.get ();
```

Как я могу изменить переменную `$scope.number` вызвав в контроллере`MainController` метод фабрики `$ scope.number = Number.get();` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я для удобства в таких случаях завожу алиасы контроллеров.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as main">
   <div ng-controller="SecondController as second">{{main.number}}</div>
</div>
```

тогда в контроллере лучше использовать `this.number = Number.get();`.
Но это на мой вкус, и если не нравится такая запись, то тогда можно использовать `{{$parent.number}}`.

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <div ng-controller="SecondController">{{$parent.number}}</div>
</div>
```

`$scope.$parent.number` - в контроллере second

Answer (score 0):

В `MainController` храните переменную как свойство объекта, например `$scope.data = {}; $scope.data.number = Number.get ();`, в `SecondController` используйте  непосредственно объект `data` родительского контроллера и его свойство `data.number`, при изменении значения свойства `number` в любом контроллере, оно будет изменяться в другом.

Пример: http://plnkr.co/edit/0exNqaDL1edmg0LJK0Sv?p=preview